# An interesting version of the problem “balls into bins”

Tags: pr.probability, co.combinatorics, computer-science

Consider n people, each has k identical balls. Each people choose k different bins from m bins, constrained by the condition that there are no two people choose exactly the same k bins. For instance, there are 6 people A,B,C,D,E,F, each hold 2 balls and there are 4 different bins①，②，③，④. If A choose ①②, B choose ①③， C choose ①④, D choose ②③，E choose ②④，and F choose③④, then we call it a proper configuration since no two people choose exactly the same 2 bins

Now each people flip a unbiased coin, if HEAD appears then he put all his ball into the k bins he has chosen, each bin with one ball. He will do nothing if TAIL appears. Here comes the problem, given a proper configuration, everyone flip a coin and behave the way we described above. Can we infer the coin result of each people based on the number of balls in each bin?

Comment: It should be clearly stated the the choice of bins for each person is public knowledge, otherwise the answer is clearly no.  

Comment: If you find one ball in each of the $4$ bins, this could come from $A+F$, $B+E$, or $C+D$. Is that really what you wanted to ask?

Comment: This is a question about enumerating bipartite graphs with given degree sequences, under a weak condition that two vertices on one side can't have the same neighbours on the other side.  Under reasonable conditions the number of solutions will grow faster than exponentially as $m,n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Tony Huynh  That's true, the choice of bins for each person is public knowledge. Thanks for your reminding

Comment: @Douglas Zare I kown there eixsts multiple results sometimes i.e. we cannot infer the results of each people. Actually,what i want is some konwledge on the probability that this situation occurs.Put it another way, given m,n and k, can we bound the probability that we couldn't infer a unique result?

Comment: @Brendan McKay Is the 'degree' refer to the number of people who have chosen a certain bin? since the 'degree' of each people is exactly k. Can you give any details to show that he number of solutions will grow faster than exponentially as m,n→∞? Thank you!

Comment: There might be an interesting problem or two, but you need to specify what you mean better. Are you asking the odds that if people choose bins randomly and flip coins randomly, and there is ambiguity? Or are you looking for "proper configurations" so that ambiguity is particularly likely or unlikely? Do you want a minimax result? There are other possibilities. I was thinking about rewriting this question to include your comments but I don't want to change the meaning.